# Создание массива размер которого вычисляется на этапе компиляции (expression must have a constant value)

Tags: c++, массивы, static-cast

Почему компилятор ругается на такой код:

```
...
const double X_MIN = 2.0;
const double X_MAX = 3.0;
const double H = .1;
...
const int n = static_cast<int>((X_MAX - X_MIN)/H) + 1;
double arrResQuanc[n] = { 0 };
```

Err: expression must have a constant value

Например этот код компилируется без проблем

```
const int K_MIN = 1;
const int K_MAX = 10;
const int nK = K_MAX - K_MIN + 1;
double arrXk[nK] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Возьмите другой (`g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` жрет и не давиться)

Answer (score 0):

А вы попробуйте проще:

```
const int i = 1.22;
constexpr int n = i;
```

правильно, потому что правое выражение содержит целое, которое является константным выражением `1`, а для чисел с плавающей точкой не так, потому что для них проводится экспоненциальная запись(читайте как хранятся double).  Вы можете написать:

```
const double d = 1.22 /3;
```

Кажется что результат должен быть константным выражением, поскольку делятся два литерала. Но это не так:

```
constexpr double e = d;
```

уже является ошибкой, потому что  `d` может иметь бесконечно или очень много знаков после плавающей точки, и в зависимости от показателья степени(экспоненты), может быть представлен по разному, и в итоге будет округлен, дабы вмещаться в выделенные для типа байты. Если взять 10 знаков, то это число:   `40666.66667 / 10^5` или же вам может быть нужно округление до 6 знаков? Тогда это число `0.40667` и так далее.  Теперь эти два числа умножте на `10^5` и получите совершенно разные целые. Надеюсь я смог объяснить почему одним словом константное целое воспринимается также как константное выражение, а константное число с плавающей точкой не считается и  константным выражением. Об этом компилятору явно нужно сказать, указав явно, что это не константа а именно constexpr

Answer (score -1):

Всё дело в том, что `const` к переменной это приставка для оптимизации компилятора и надёжности к программированию. Программист может отправлять ссылку на переменную, которая постоянно меняется и её может передавать как константу.
Размеры массива должны быть заданы не простой переменной, а той, чьё значение уже вычислено на этапе компиляции. И обозначение `constexpr` именно это и делает.

```cpp
constexpr double X_MIN = 2.0;
constexpr double X_MAX = 3.0;
constexpr double H = .1;
constexpr int n = static_cast<int>((X_MAX - X_MIN)/H) + 1;
double arrResQuanc[n] = { 0 };
```